# Permanently disable hotspot in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, 18.04, network-manager, hot-spot

Our company is totally open-source. Mostly we work on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. Most of our employees have turned on the hotspot in the network settings. We want to block all these hotspot connections. Is there a way to block or permanently disable the hotspot option in the terminal or the network-manager?

Comment: Please be precise with Ubuntu releases; Ubuntu desktop & server releases are *yy.mm* in format, and *yy* is used for specialist releases like Ubuntu Core 16 (for IoT appliances).   You maybe working with all IoT appliances at your work rather than servers or desktops (thus the 16 & 18 references) but I suspect you don't mean that.

Comment: Do your employees have `sudo` privileges?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli - yes, they have sudo privileges.

Comment: @guiverc - we are using normal Desktop LTS on both versions.