# users are creating mobile hotspot in our office how to disable permanently hotspot option on ubuntu 16.4

Tags: delete, hot-spot

In my office we have ubuntu systems for all the users but nowadays users are creating hotspot in user account and they dont have admin access too. how can i disable mobile hotspot option on ubuntu 16.4

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 16.4, there is 16.04 is that the version?

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021 so you may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: Hi we have ubuntu 20.10 also but we dont have option to disable permanently mobile hotspot option

Comment: How does users create  hotspot ? Please update your question with the actual commands.

Comment: @SorenA On Kubuntu 20.10 at least this is just a matter of clicking on an icon...Disabling the ability on the other side, is really a good and useful question in a working environment

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214436/permanently-disable-hotspot-in-ubuntu-16-04-and-18-04 and that one is also unanswered.